# Firebase Web Version 9 updateProfile not updating the authorized user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Web version 9 in a react app. I have a sign-up form with first name, email, and password inputs. When the form is submitted, I need to create an authorized user with Firebase and immediately update that new user's first name and profile picture.

I'm using two Firebase auth functions - createUserWithEmailAndPassword() and updateProfile(). A new user is always created when the form is submitted, but the profile updates only happen once in a while. I haven't been able to pinpoint the cases when the profile update is successful.

Any ideas on what I'm missing? Would love some feedback and guidance. Thank you!

Here's the code for the sign-up page.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  StyledHeader,
  StyledFooter,
  StyledDropdown,
  StyledForm,
} from '../styles';
import {
  getAuth,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  updateProfile,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import { ShortFooter, LanguageSelect, Form } from '../components';
import { logo, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5 } from '../assets';

const SignUp = ({ children }) => {
  const [firstName, setfirstName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [isFirstNameEmpty, setIsFirstNameEmpty] = useState(true);
  const [isEmailEmpty, setIsEmailEmpty] = useState(true);
  const [isPasswordEmpty, setIsPasswordEmpty] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(true);
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(true);
  const isInvalid = firstName === '' || email === '' || password === '';
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const userProfileImgs = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5];

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // ️ scroll to top on page load
      window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
    }, 100);
  }, []);

  const handlefirstNameChange = (firstName) => {
    if (firstName.length !== 0) {
      setIsFirstNameEmpty(false);
    } else {
      setIsFirstNameEmpty(true);
    }
  };

  const handleEmailChange = (email) => {
    if (email.length !== 0) {
      setIsEmailEmpty(false);
    } else {
      setIsEmailEmpty(true);
    }
  };

  const handlePasswordChange = (password) => {
    if (password.length !== 0) {
      setIsPasswordEmpty(false);
    } else {
      setIsPasswordEmpty(true);
    }
  };

  const handleCheckbox = () => {
    setChecked((checked) => !checked);
  };

  const handleLearnMore = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsShown((isShown) => !isShown);
  };

  const handleSignUp = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      // firebase work!
      const auth = getAuth();
      let { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      );
      console.debug(`User ${user.uid} created`);

      // updating the user's profile with their first name and a random profile image
      await updateProfile(user, {
        displayName: firstName,
        photoURL:
          userProfileImgs[Math.floor(Math.random() * userProfileImgs.length)],
      });
      console.debug(`User profile updated`);

      // navigate to the profile page
      navigate('/profile');
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.message === 'Firebase: Error (auth/email-already-in-use).') {
        setError('That email is already in use, please try again.');
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <StyledHeader height="120">
        <div className="header__background">
          <div className="header__frame">
            <div>
              <Link to="/">
                <img className="header__logo" src={logo} alt="Netflix Logo" />
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
          <form onSubmit={handleSignUp} className="form__container">
            <StyledForm padding="20px 68px 40px">
              <Form
                error={error}
                isEmailEmpty={isEmailEmpty}
                email={email}
                setEmail={setEmail}
                handleEmailChange={handleEmailChange}
                isPasswordEmpty={isPasswordEmpty}
                password={password}
                setPassword={setPassword}
                handlePasswordChange={handlePasswordChange}
                isInvalid={isInvalid}
                checked={checked}
                handleCheckbox={handleCheckbox}
                handleLearnMore={handleLearnMore}
                isShown={isShown}
                isFirstNameEmpty={isFirstNameEmpty}
                firstName={firstName}
                setfirstName={setfirstName}
                handlefirstNameChange={handlefirstNameChange}
                method="post"
              />
            </StyledForm>
          </form>

          <div className="signIn__footer-container">
            <div className="signIn__footer-background">
              <StyledFooter
                backgroundColor="transparent"
                padding="10px 70px 40px 70px"
              >
                <ShortFooter>
                  <StyledDropdown>
                    <LanguageSelect />
                  </StyledDropdown>
                </ShortFooter>
              </StyledFooter>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {children}
      </StyledHeader>
    </>
  );
};

export default SignUp;
```

This is the error I'm getting in the console.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Itrsz.png)

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `updateProfile` function?

Comment: @adsy yes! Just updated my question with the full signup page for you. Thank you for your time looking at this with me.

Comment: No worries! I'm wondering if you are seeing any complaints from firebase in your network pane in the dev tools? Also wondering if maybe one of `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` or `getAuth` throws, which would mean it doesn't reach the later `updateProfile` code. Does your first `console.debug` get printed?

Comment: @adsy yes! Confirming the first console.debug is always printed whenever the form is submitted with new user info. Confirming I'm seeing a 400 error for a POST request to this link in the console as well --> https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:update?key=REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY (removed my key here)

Comment: Right, the 400 will be the problem. Click on that request and have a look at the response body -- is there an error in there?

Comment: @adsy, sweet! Just updated the post with the error message I'm getting in the console.

Comment: So you now need to go to the network pane and view the response body. The console error is indicative, but you need to inspect the network: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/ and check what the response body is

Comment: @adsy ahh gotcha. Checked it out and I'm seeing "This request has no response data available."

Comment: Hmmm. In your console picture you posted, where it says "fetch failed loading" at the bottom, click that little arrow to expand and report back whats in there.

Comment: @adsy nvm my last comment had a filter on. Now seeing "Failed to load response data: Request content was evicted from inspector cache."

Comment: @adsy when clicking that arrow for "fetch failed loading" I'm seeing it contains the same information shown in the picture.

Comment: The inspector cache thing is quite rare. I have a mild suspicion that you are exceeding the allowed input body length. One reason for this error is you can't see the response because its too lareg. `userProfileImgs[Math.floor(Math.random() * userProfileImgs.length)],` implies there's an image involved. Try without `photoURL` out of interest, does it still fail?

Comment: @adsy  ayyyeee that's exactly what it was, you got it! Works every time now. So thankful for your assistance with this...was breaking things/researching about this almost all day :)

Comment: No worries! Yeh this one was actually quite obscure.

Answer (score 0):

Based on how my app was set up I ultimately decided to remove the photoURL property altogether since it could be defined elsewhere in the app. After testing, only one of my images worked. This is why I experienced the full profile updates working out sometimes since random images were selected each time a new user signs up. I ended up sticking wth this image as the default image.

As @adsy mentioned, my profile updates weren't happening consistently because certain profile images I had exceeded the allowed input body length for this property. The example in the Docs shows a link with 43 characters but no other information. The path to the profile images in the question are much shorter than this so I still need some understanding.

After researching a bit, I didn't come across the maximum limit set. It's now something to contact Google Developer's support team about. If anyone has the information for the allowed input body length for this property, feel free to share it on this post.

Thanks!

```
 const handleSignUp = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      // firebase work!
      const auth = getAuth();
      let { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      );
      console.debug(`User ${user.uid} created`);

      // updating the user's profile with their first name
      await updateProfile(user, {
        displayName: firstName,
      });
      console.debug(`User profile updated`);

      // navigate to the profile page
      navigate('/profile');
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.message === 'Firebase: Error (auth/email-already-in-use).') {
        setError('That email is already in use, please try again.');
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: You'll want to create your own `users` document to store properties for each user such as photoUrl, first name, last name, favorite color, etc. ...and just an FYI: in my opinion, after implementing all flavors of auth - it's best to simply use email link authentication (like Craigslist does) that way there is no password to forget (and no pwd reset handlers to code). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth

Comment: @RonnieRoyston okay sweet! Will keep this in mind, appreciate you sharing your opinion, and the doc. I see where you're coming from...thanks so much.